# Returning a div in an anchor tag

Tags: .net, html, tabs, asp.net-mvc-4, anchor

I was wondering if it was possible to return a div, instead of a full/partial view in an anchor tag, in mvc 4, in the form of:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#div1" id="tab1">div1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#div2" id="tab2">div2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

    <div id="div1">
        Content of div1
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        Content of div2
    </div>
```

If this method exists, please let me know how to do it, if not, ill have to go back to the drawing board.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the content on the page? or are you wanting to load it in dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use JQueryUI tabs for this purpose.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Sigh, I wasnt naming my divs in the correct format, eg. tabs-1. Much love for your help dude :)